# Требуется правильно вывести отображение хода в ProgressBar

Tags: c#, wpf

Добрый день, коллеги.

Просьба помочь с правильным отображением всего хода загрузки папки с FTP.
Код ниже позволяет скачать всю директорию целиком.
Работает через backgroundworker, и нужна помощь именно с отображением скаченных файлов.

Пример: На FTP 53 файла(и в корне, и в подпапках), нужно отображение общего хода скачивания, то есть 1\53, 2\53 и до 100%. Надеюсь получилось объяснить  Код:

```
void DownloadFtpDirectory(string url, NetworkCredential credentials, string localPath)
{

    FtpWebRequest listRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    listRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
    listRequest.Credentials = credentials;

    List<string> lines = new List<string>();

    using (FtpWebResponse listResponse = (FtpWebResponse)listRequest.GetResponse())
    using (Stream listStream = listResponse.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader listReader = new StreamReader(listStream))
    {
        while (!listReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            lines.Add(listReader.ReadLine());
        }
    }

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        string[] tokens = line.Split(new[] { ' ' }, 9, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string name = tokens[8];
        string permissions = tokens[0];

        string localFilePath = Path.Combine(localPath, name);
        string fileUrl = url + name;

        if (permissions[0] == 'd')
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(localFilePath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(localFilePath);
            }

        DownloadFtpDirectory(fileUrl + "/", credentials, localFilePath);
        }
        else
        {
            FtpWebRequest downloadRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fileUrl);
            downloadRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            downloadRequest.Credentials = credentials;

            using (FtpWebResponse downloadResponse = (FtpWebResponse)downloadRequest.GetResponse())
            using (Stream sourceStream = downloadResponse.GetResponseStream())
            using (Stream targetStream = File.Create(localFilePath))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                int read;

                while ((read = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);

                    //Worker.ReportProgress("???????"); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Подсчитайте количество `int countLines = lines.Count;` и в цикле `foreach (string line in lines)` вычитайте единицу из `countLines` и выводите результат как прогресс.

Comment: Да, и бэкграундвокер устаревшая хрень. Почитайте про TPL, `IProgress` и `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: Если вы отображаете скачанные байты, то лучше двойной прогресс. Первый показывает прогресс текущего файла, а второй прогресс количества файлов. Конечно лучше знать общий вес, но даже с линейным прогрессом куда нагляднее одиночного.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы советовал тебе сначала вытягивать общий вес всех файлов и ориентироватся на него(.Maximum = даный вес;, а в валью вписывать уже вес уже скачанного). Что бы не было ситуации что на фтп будет 100 файлов по 100 килобайт и 1 файл на 1 гигабайт.И последний файл в прогрессбаре будет показыватся как равная по размеру часть общей информации.

Так же согласен с Bulson. Лучше смотреть в сторону TPL.

Comment: Andrew, спасибо за дельный совет, но, к сожалению, тот [метод](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32348066/6849285), что я нашел, просчитывает директорию продолжительное время.
Если наведете на правильный путь, буду благодарен.

А по поводу TPL, почитал, что это за зверь, но все махинации провожу на net 3.5, и если не ошибаюсь, он не поддерживается(либо не полностью)